# Possible to inject thumbnail photos into AD via cfldap?

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory

Does anyone have a way to inject thumbnail photos of users into AD? When I get data via cfldap, I can see the entry for thumbnailphoto, but the entry for MY record (which has a photo attached to it manually) has an empty string in that field.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's any way to do it.  I've never been able to figure out how to use binary data as an attribute using CFLDAP.

I always end up using Java if I have to do this.

Comment: Sorry for the so old post comment, but do you have any news in this case? can you explain how to use java + coldfusion to do that?