# How to change the user image using cfldap?

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

I'm able to get all the values that I want from cfldap.
But when I try to update the user image I don't know how to send the correct value for the binary image attribute.

I tried getting the image variable from the cffile upload

```
<cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="file" destination="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test" nameconflict="OVERWRITE"  result="image" />
```

Also tried using cfimage with a static image -

```
<cfimage action="read" source="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\image.png" name="anotherImage">
```

Or even with

```
<cffile action="READBINARY" file="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\image.png" variable="BinaryImageContent">
```

But in any case, when I call

```
<cfldap action="modify" 
  DN="#results.dn#" 
  attributes="thumbnailPhoto=#obj.image#" 
  modifytype="replace" 
  server="myserver"
  username="mydomain\myuser" 
password="mypass">
```

The #results.dn# is the DN from the user  that I get before (Everything ok on that)
I created the #obj.image# to be able to try all types of variables

Also tried these params:

```
  <cfset obj.test1 = BinaryImageContent />
  <cfdump var="#imageGetBlob(anotherImage)#" />
  <cfdump var="#toString(obj.test1)#" />
```

By the way, the error that I get its

> One or more of the required attributes may be missing or incorrect or
>   you do not have permissions to execute this operation on the server.

The problem is that I'm using the domain administrator account to update that

(THIS ERROR IS SOLVED - The network guys hadn't given me this permission... now I have it).

Now what I'm using is the following:

```
<cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="file" destination="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test" nameconflict="OVERWRITE"  result="imagem" />
<cfset filename = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\#imagem.serverFile#">
<cffile action="readbinary" file="#filename#" variable="img">
<cfset imgStr = BinaryEncode(img, "hex")>
<cfset imgStr2 = REReplace(imgStr, "..", "\\\0", "ALL")>
<cfldap
  action="modify" 
  DN="#results.dn#" 
  attributes="thumbnailPhoto=#imgStr2#" 
  modifytype="replace" 
  server="myserver"
  username="mydomain\myuser" 
  password="mypass"
>
```

but I get this binary code

[image]

Whats strange, is that before I had a binary code like -1-41 and now, nothing similar...

and when I try to show the pic

[image]

And this is one correct image....
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The original code sample below shows how it *could* work if ColdFusion wouldn't have a bug (or "very unfortunate design decision") in CFLDAP.

CFLDAP encodes the parameter values you pass to it before sending them to the server. This is nice because you don't have to worry about value encoding. But... it is also not helpful because it means you can't send encoded values yourself anymore, since CF invariably encodes them *again*.

Bottom line: As far as LDAP is concerned, encoding a file into a hex-string is correct, but CFLDAP mangles that string before sending it to the server. Combined with the fact that CFLDAP does not accept raw binary data this means that you can't use it to update binary attributes.

The comments contain a suggestion for a 3rd-party command line tool that can easily substitute CFLDAP for this task.

---

You need to send an encoded string to the server as the attribute value. The encoding scheme for binary data in LDAP queries has the form of `attribute=\01\02\03\ab\af\cd`.

Read your image into a byte array, encode that array into a hex string and prefix every encoded byte with a backslash.

```
<cffile action="readbinary" file="#filename#" variable="img">
<cfset imgStr = BinaryEncode(img, "hex")>
<cfset imgStr = REReplace(imgStr, "..", "\\\0", "ALL")>

<cfldap
  action="modify" 
  DN="#results.dn#" 
  attributes="thumbnailPhoto=#imgStr#" 
  modifytype="replace" 
  server="myserver"
  username="mydomain\myuser" 
  password="mypass"
>
```

Also don't forget what [the documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-j-l/cfldap.html) has to say about `modifyType`.

Comment: I get this error as it looks like I'm sending one data to big for the value

An error has occured while trying to execute modify :[LDAP: error code 19 - 00002082: AtrErr: DSID-03151314, #1: 0: 00002082: , problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 160023 (thumbnailPhoto):len 466635 ].

Comment: See http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2010/11/03/the-thumbnailphoto-attribute-explained/. The `thumbnailPhoto` size is limited to 100 Kb and the recommended size is 96 x 96 pixels. Use CF's photo editing functions to make an actual thumbnail out of your image. Also compare [the MSDN on `thumbnailPhoto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221395.aspx), especially the `rangeUpper` part.

Comment: So, actually the network guys lied to me that the admin user had the permission to change ldap accounts... now it has and I don't receive the error that I dont have permission...

Anyway, I receive a strange binary when I do this... will update my question with the data and image

Comment: @GuilhermeSilva The admin user *definitely* has the right to change the photo. Not every "access denied" message you see actually means "access denied", though.

Comment: sorry, but the network guys had one web admin user that I was using... was this user that didnt had all the privileges before... sorry

Now it has the privileges...

I'm sending the images in 96x96 and less than 100kb but no success in updating that

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3474239/18771) suggests CFLDAP can't do it. It looks as if it employs its own escaping scheme before sending the data, resulting in double-escaped data arriving at the server. Maybe you can look into the possibility of using a 3rd-party tool. [AdMod](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/admod/index.htm) springs to mind, you can use it with `<cfexecute>`.

Comment: A quick comment, when I use 
     <cfset ark = #BinaryDecode(imgStr,'HEX')# /> it gives me the correct binary code from before... so If I could send this to the server....  but I get this error "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings."

Comment: CFLDAP accepts only strings, the LDAP server accepts only strings. Strings are the right way to do this. Unfortunately CFLDAP has effectively a bug which leads to double encoding. This is a showstopper, you can't use CFLDAP for this. Instead of re-inventing it in Java (as you have asked on the other thread), I *strongly* recommend you look into using AdMod or a similar tool.

Comment: Thanks! will see how admod works... never heard of that before.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't have to use *that* tool, it's just one of many. All I'm saying is that a developed and tested tool is preferable to writing the code from scratch.  And a command line tool is very convenient to use with ColdFusion. Sorry about the confusion with the hex encoding in my answer, I actually assumed CF would play nice here.